# Error cuando implemento una librería nueva a mi proyecto Android

Tags: java, android-studio, github, compilar, numberpicker

Estoy intentando implementar esta librería en mi proyecto.

implementación **io.github.ShawnLin013: selector de números: 2.4.13**

Cuando sincronizo el Gradel funciona perfectamente, pero cuando ejecuto la app me da el siguiente error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.proxectofinal, PID: 7683
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.proxectofinal/com.example.proxectofinal.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14 in com.example.proxectofinal:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #19 in com.example.proxectofinal:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14 in com.example.proxectofinal:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #19 in com.example.proxectofinal:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19 in com.example.proxectofinal:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.proxectofinal.FragmentLiga.onCreateView(FragmentLiga.java:148)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:392)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1261)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1117)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1261)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1117)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.proxectofinal.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:153)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Aquí está mi archivo build.gradel a nivel de app

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.proxectofinal"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'io.github.ShawnLin013:number-picker:2.4.13'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:20.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:4.3'



    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
}
```

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

os comparto el content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

La aplicación funciona perfectamente si no implemento esa libreria. Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿A caso modificaste algo en el código?

Comment: Agrega  por favor content_main.xml

Answer (score 1):

El problema no tiene que ver con las dependencias, indica que cuando tratas de inflar el layout de tu activity se tiene un problema en el layout, ya sea porque no existe la vista a inflar o la clase a cargar tiene un error.

> ComponentInfo{com.example.proxectofinal/com.example.proxectofinal.MainActivity}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14 in
> com.example.proxectofinal:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line
> #19 in com.example.proxectofinal:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment

En este caso el layout `content_main.xml` tiene definido un Fragment pero este tiene un error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```